Rational points on the Fermat quintic surface
The Fermat quintic surface is the surface
\begin{align}
V : X_0^5 + X_1^5 + X_2^5 + X_3^5 = 0
\end{align}
in $\mathbb{P}^3$. It is a surface of general type.
In their book "Diophantine Geometry: an introduction", Silverman and Hindry say that $V$ not known to satisfy the Bombieri--Lang conjecture, in the sense that it is not known whether $V$ has finitely many rational points not lying on rational or elliptic curves.
Has this been answered now?
I am also interested in rational points on the surface
\begin{align}
V_d : X_0^d + X_1^d = X_2^d + X_3^d
\end{align}
where $d \geq 6$. I think all $V_d$ are of general type, being surfaces in $\mathbb{P}^3$ of degree $d \geq 5$.

I don't believe the state of knowledge to the extent that you are expecting has improved since the Hindry-Silverman book was published. In particular, I do not believe a single case of Bombieri-Lang has been proved.

In general, a smooth degree $d$ hypersurface $V$ in $\mathbb P^n$ is of general type if and only if $d\ge n+3$, since $\mathcal K_V \cong \mathcal O_V(d-n-2)$, so $\mathcal K_V$ is ample if $d\ge n+3$, and not ample otherwise. So you are correct that your $V_d$ is of general type for $d\ge5$. AFAIK, Bombieri-Lang is not known for $V_d(\mathbb Q)$. It does follow from an appropriately formulated $abcd$-conjecture.

With $n=3$, inequality $d\geq n+3$ reduces to $d\geq 6$, why $d\geq 5$?
